# Xamarin iOS | Error Connecting Xamarin Build Host from Visual Studio on Windows

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

We are attempting to connect to a Xamarin build host running on a Mac Mini (OS X 10.11 Yosemite) to a Visual Studio running on a Windows 8.1 Machine. We have updated Xamarin.iOS to same version on both system.

**The issue:**
My Visual Studio can detect the build host and asks for PIN to pair with the build host. But even if I'm entering the same PIN, it never accepts, and keeps giving this error(PFA Screenshots):

> The PIN you entered was invalid.
>   Please ensure you have entered the correct PIN.
>   You may have to close this dialog and retry from Visual Studio.

[image]
[image]

I've restarted both systems and tried to unpair and pair again with new PIN, but no success.

Needless to say, but both systems are on same network and VS can detect the build host.
My Mac Details are in attached image –
[image]

Visual Studio Details: 
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

Comment: On your Mac, can you `telnet localhost 5000` (or from your Windows box if you have telnet available `telnet yourMacIpAddress 5000` ? If so you should get no response text upon initial connection. Now type `HELO` and hit return, what do you get as a reply?

Comment: @RobertN Hi, thanks for your response, I'm fairly new to using a Mac so pardon if I do something wrong. I used the `telnet localhost 5000` and the response was `Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.` I didn't get you with the `HELO` part, is that a command or an argument?

Comment: Command, type `HELO` and press Return after getting connected

Comment: The response: `QC-Mac-mini:~ mySystem$ telnet localhost 5000
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
HELO
ERROR: Another instance is running
Connection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: Is your Windows PC connected right now? If so, close Visual Studio or disconnect the network cable and try it over again

Comment: Disabled ethernet on my PC and tried again, this was the result this time `QC-Mac-mini:~ omprakash$ telnet localhost 5000
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
objc[66118]: Class WebAnimationController is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/Versions/A/WebKitLegacy and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
HELO
MTBSERVERPORTS:62592;62595`.

Comment: Something is not right, which version of the Build Host are you running? Can you upgrade to the Xamarin Mac Agent? As it replaces the PIN pairing and uses a SSH tunnel to login to the Mac http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.0/ &  https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1733609-additional-build-host-connection-troubleshooting-steps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92938/discussion-between-samy-s-rathore-and-robertn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting to your build host via telnet you should not be receiving any response *until* you enter `HELO`.

The response that you are getting before the `HELO MTBSERVERPORTS:62592;62595` is incorrect (a Xamarin bug).

```
objc[66118]: Class WebAnimationController is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebKitLegacy.f‌​ramework/Versions/A/WebKitLegacy and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

If you are running any thing older that the Xamarin 3.9 release, you need to upgrade. If that does not help, either contact Xamarin Support to help troubleshoot why this is happening or upgrade to the Xamarin 4.0 for Visual Studio.

Personally, I would upgrade to the Xamarin 4.0 for Visual Studio (currently an alpha release) as it replaces the PIN pairing with a SSH tunnel that avoids all of the older issues with 3.0 Build Host connection problems.

Re: http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.0/

> This version also introduces the new Xamarin Mac Agent which replaces
>   the old Xamarin Build Host with a new approach taking advantage of the
>   built-in MacOS Remote Login feature based on SSH for a faster and more
>   reliable connectivity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your comments and answer helped a lot. I was running Xamarin 3.9 release, but upgrading to Xamarin 4.0 for Visual Studio did the trick for me. My Build Host is now connected with the VS. :)

Comment: That is great to hear, the 4.0 version fixed all of our issues with remote build connection (at least so far!)

Answer (score 0):

First check firewall rule on your both machines if the port (5000) is not blocked.
Second read this link 
https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1733609-additional-build-host-connection-troubleshooting-steps 
Try to connect manually by telnet.

Comment: Please add some summary / relevant information about what is explained in that link.